# Hiding output of stepAIC in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

How best will I hide the output of stepAIC from the output in the Rmarkdown.
I tried `echo = FALSE`, `message = FALSE` but it would not work. Any leads kindly?

````
---
title: "Multivariate Regression"
author: "Moses Otieno"
date: "11/05/2021"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

library(gtsummary) # Grammar of tables 

```

```{r regression}
mod1 <- glm(response ~ trt + age + grade , trial, family = binomial)

step.model <- MASS::stepAIC(mod1, direction = "both")

t1 <- tbl_regression(step.model, exponentiate = TRUE)
t1
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `trace=0` ? From `?MASS::stepAIC`,

> trace: if positive, information is printed during the running of
> ‘stepAIC’.  Larger values may give more information on the
> fitting process.

This is the best way to do it, but if you couldn't do that then `capture.output()` would also work:

```r
junk <- capture.output(step.model <- MASS::stepAIC(mod1, direction = "both"))
```

If you put the `stepAIC()` call *in a separate chunk*, I think specifying `results="hide"` as a chunk option would also work.

Comment: This is amazing. I had encapsulated it in a function so the trace component works perfectly fine. The other options are good as well. It helped a great deal.